# Add a text output in the heading variable

Tags: r, shinyapps

I have a tab which shows the number of days for which forecast has been done.

I wanted to include at the top, for how many days the forecast has been done.

So, I used the following code in the ui.R file

```
tabPanel('Forecast of cases in the region',
                         (fluidRow(
                                     h3('Forecast for',textOutput('Text1'),'number of days')
                                   )),
                            DT::dataTableOutput("Table1")
                             )
```

Here is the part of server.R file -

```
reactive(
                output$Text1<-input$Days
            )
            output$Table1<-DT::renderDataTable({
                k<-as.data.frame(future())
                k[1:3]<-round(k[1:3])
                colnames(k)<-c('Forecast','lower Confidence Interval',
                               'upper Confidence Interval')
                dat<-DT::datatable(k,
                                   options=list(
                                       paging=TRUE,pageLength=7))
                
                })
```

But the output was given without the text being present

[image: Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate the whole text in `renderText`:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("days", "Days", "10"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel('Forecast of cases in the region',
               fluidRow(
                 h3(textOutput("value"))
               )),
               DT::dataTableOutput("Table1")
      ),
      tabPanel("Other", verbatimTextOutput("textOutput")),
    )
  )
  
  
  
  

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$value <- renderText({
    req(input$days)
    paste("Forecast for ",input$days," days") })
  
  output$Table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(iris)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)





server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$value <- renderText({
    req(input$days)
    paste("Forecast for ",input$days," days") })
  
  output$Table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(iris)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I want it inside the tab panel

Comment: You can just replace inside `tabpanel` the current code `h3('Forecast for',textOutput('Text1'),'number of days')` by the `h3(textOutput("value"))`I propose